# PHP - How do I write to a file?

Tags: php, file, server

I have this bit of code in my index.php page, it's simple but I am a PHP noob. I just want to be able to write, well, append this one line of code to a .txt file every time someone visits the page, but I can't get it to work. 
I don't even get the error message. 
The server is running off a Pi.

```
<?php

$fileDir = fopen('/mnt/data_8GB/webCrawlLog.txt', 'a');
    if ($fileDir === NULL) echo "ERROR";
    else {fwrite($fileDir, date('H:i:s:'));}
fclose($fileDir);

?>
```

TL:DR
Just trying to write to a .txt using PHP, and maybe have PHP create a file if no file exists.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. Also make sure the folder has permissions to write to it.

Comment: `file_put_contents('/mnt/data_8GB/webCrawlLog.txt', date('H:i:s:').PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND);`

Comment: `fopen` returns a file handle on success, or a boolean false if it fails; you're using `===` to perform a strict comparison with the return value. So if the `fopen` fails, you won't go into the ERROR line, but you still won't be able to write.

Comment: You're also going to want and do `fwrite($fileDir, date('H:i:s:') . "\n");` otherwise, you'll end up with content inside one long line. 9 times out of 10, it's a permissions issue.

Comment: TL;DR? The PHP Documentation will help you: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php

Comment: Thanks andrewsi, you were right about the "===" to "==" issue. That fixed it not given the ERROR message. 
 Fred -ii, thanks for the "\n", and yes it seems to be a permission issue. Saving to /tmp works but not /mnt locations.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP code works, try writing to `/tmp` instead and you will see it fill.

I imagine your PHP is being run by apache ? That means the user apache is running as (usually `www-data`) will need write access to the folder.

You actually need write access to the whole path also running

```
namei -l /mnt/data_8GB/
```

should show the permissions on both folders, Both will need write access for www-data either as user, group or world. Though group is preferable.

Comment: Tried writing to /tmp, same issue.

Running namei -l /mnt/data_8GB/ gives:

drwxr-xr-x root root /
drwxr-xr-x root root mnt
drwxr-xr-x pi   pi   data_8GB

Comment: Ok, so I changed my code a bit:

<?php

$fileDir = fopen('/tmp/webCrawlLog.txt', 'a');
 if ($fileDir == NULL) echo "ERROR";
 else {fwrite($fileDir, "Day Crawled: " . date('Y:m:d') . " " . "Time Crawled: " . date('H:i:s') . " " . "IP: " . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "\n");}
fclose($fileDir);

?>

And this works fine. It creates a file, can append to it, gives me the info, works great. Only thing is is that I still can't save to my /mnt/data_8GB

Comment: Root is owner and group of both. Chown www-data both of the folders

Comment: pi /mnt $ sudo chown www-data data_8GB
chown: changing ownership of `data_8GB': Operation not permitted

Comment: What are the mount flags ? And what's the file system

Comment: Are you asking what I used to mount the USB? Here:
sudo mount -t vfat -o uid=pi,gid=pi /dev/sda1 /mnt/data_8GB